# Mapreduce Vs Spark Vs Storm Vs Drill - For Small files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-storm, apache-drill

I know spark does the in memory computation and is much faster then MapReduce. 
I was wondering how well does spark work for say records  < 10000 ? 
I have huge number of files around ( each file having around 10000 records , say 100 column file) coming into my hadoop data platform and i need to perform some data quality checks before i load then into hbase.

I do the data quality check in hive which uses MapReduce at the back-end. For each file it takes about 8 mins and thats pretty bad for me.
Will spark give me a better performance lets say 2-3 mins ?

I know I got to do a bench marking but i was trying to understand the basics here before i really get going with spark. 
As I recollect creating RDD's for the first time will be an overhead and since i got to create a new RDD for each incoming file that going to cost me a bit.

I am confused which would be the best approach for me -  spark , drill, storm or Mapreduce itself ?

Comment: Given the information you provided, its nearly impossible to answer this question. What specific number = "huge number of files"?  What type of data is in those files? What is the exact "data quality check" that you are performing that takes 8 mins?  What specific hardware are you working with -- 1k nodes or 10 nodes?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 : I will receive about 4000 files a day. The file contains data fields separated by pipes (Text data). The kind of data quality i perform is on the each column (File level checks) to make the file contains valid data, no missing values, null string , invalid date formats and so.I have about 100 columns and i do the check for about 50 columns which might increase going forward. Currently i work in a three node cluster which i know is not a good option. But what i was looking for is to get a feel of performance that i can get.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 : Since i have about 10000 records, increasing the number of nodes might not really help, as the data will always be less than my block size (Correct me if i am wrong), I right now use mapr hadoop distro. if i say that i have a cluster of 10 nodes how will it perform better ?. i Use oozie to schedule the task so oozie's lag also has to be taken care of

Answer (score 1):

I am just exploring the performance of **Drill vs Spark vs Hive** over around millions of records. Dill & Spark both are around **5-10 times faster** in my case (*I did not perform any performance test over cluster with significant RAM, I just tested on single node*) The reason for fast computation - both of them perform the in-memory computation.

The performance of drill & spark is almost comparable in my case. So, I can't say which one is better. You need to try this at your end.

Testing on Drill will not take much time. [Download](https://drill.apache.org/download/) the latest drill, [install](https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-the-cluster/) on your mapr hadoop cluster, add hive-storage [plugin](https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/) and perform the [query](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-hive/).